# SQL error 1064 in full outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I get the error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'full outer join adm_student_academic a on a.rollno=p.username
> where ps.degree='B' at line 1"

The query I used is as follows:

```
SELECT p.username, p.firstname, a.matric_obtain_marks
FROM  adm_student_academic a,
      profile_student AS ps,
      PROFILE p FULL OUTER JOIN adm_student_academic a
      ON a.rollno=p.username
WHERE ps.degree='BS(CS)' AND ps.batch = 'Fall 2010'
ORDER BY p.username
```

The result I want to achieve is depicted in the following example:

Suppose you have two Tables, with a single column each, and data as follows:

> A  : 1 2 3 4
> B  : 3 4 5 6

and I want the result as follows:

> a | 1      2  3 4 null
>
> b | null null 3 4 6

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `full outer join`.

Comment: then what is the solution to this problem? i want the union of all records from profile and adm_student_academics table..

Comment: Delete this question.  It is worthless.  Ask another question, providing sample data and desired results.  That question can probably be reasonably answered.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't support full outer join, but it can be simulated with a union of left outer joins:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON (...)
UNION
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM TableB b
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA a ON (...)
```

Comment: but it can also be mimicked using a *UNION of LEFT and RIGHT JOIN*